# What is the reason for `std::result_of` deprecated in C++17?

Tags: c++, templates, deprecated, c++17, result-of

I saw `std::result_of` is being deprecated in C++17.

- What is the reason for `std::result_of` deprecated in C++17?
- Also I would like to know the difference between `std::result_of` and `std::invoke_result`.

Comment: Funny, I could have sworn I wrote something on that page explaining why it got deprecated...oh wait, [I did](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of#Notes).

Comment: Why also tag this as C++14?

Comment: I had just been learning how to use that. Oh well

Answer (score 12):

T.C. already provided the obvious link, but perhaps the most horrific reason bears repeating: `result_of` involved forming the type `F(Arg1, Arg2, ...)` not for a function of those types *returning* `F` but for a function *of type* `F` accepting those types.  (After all, the return type is the result of, well, `result_of`, not the input!)

Aside from the adjustments associated with forming the function type, the only difference between the two is syntactic.

Comment: That page doesn't at all explain how to use `std::invoke_result` or `std::invoke_result_t`, only the deprecated `std::result_of`

Comment: @haelix: Add an example there if you think it’s needed.  I didn’t write that page, and explaining its use is not particularly relevant to this question.

Answer (score 9):

@haelix:

I'm totaly with you concerning the lack of example on the cppreference page. 
Here's my take:

```cpp
auto add_auto_fn(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

template<typename U, typename V>
auto add_auto_template_fn(U a, V b) {
    return a + b;
}

int fortytwo(int a, int b) { return a + 42; }

struct my_functor{
    auto operator() (int a) { return a + 42; }
};

void test_invoke_result()
{
    {
        // For functions and auto function: use < decltype(&f), Args... >
        using T = std::invoke_result< decltype(&fortytwo), int, int>::type;
        static_assert(std::is_same<T, int>::value, "");
    }
    {
        // For templated auto functions: use < decltype(&f)<Args...>, Args... >
        using T = std::invoke_result< decltype(&add_auto_template_fn<int, double>), int, double>::type;
        static_assert(std::is_same<T, double>::value, "");
    }
    {
        // For simple lambdas: use < decltype(lambda), Args... >
        auto simple_lambda = [](int a) {  return a + 42; };
        using T = std::invoke_result< decltype(simple_lambda), int>::type;
        static_assert(std::is_same<T, int>::value, "");
    }
    {
        // For generic lambdas: use < decltype(lambda), Args... >
        auto generic_lambda = [](auto a) {  return a + 42; };
        using T = std::invoke_result< decltype(generic_lambda), double>::type;
        static_assert(std::is_same<T, double>::value, "");
    }
    {
        // For functors: use < functor, Args... >
        using T = std::invoke_result< my_functor, int>::type;
        static_assert(std::is_same<T, int>::value, "");
    }

}

void test_result_of()
{
    {
        // For functions and auto function: use < decltype(&f)(Args...) >
        using T = std::result_of< decltype(&fortytwo)(int, int)>::type;
        static_assert(std::is_same<T, int>::value, "");
    }
    {
        // For templated auto functions: use < decltype(&f<Args...>)(Args...) >
        using T = std::result_of< decltype(&add_auto_template_fn<int, double>)(int, double)>::type;
        static_assert(std::is_same<T, double>::value, "");
    }
    {
        // For simple lambdas: use < decltype(lambda)(Args...) >
        auto simple_lambda = [](int a) {  return a + 42; };
        using T = std::result_of< decltype(simple_lambda)(int)>::type;
        static_assert(std::is_same<T, int>::value, "");
    }
    {
        // For generic lambdas: use < decltype(lambda)(Args...) >
        auto generic_lambda = [](auto a) {  return a + 42; };
        using T = std::result_of< decltype(generic_lambda)(double)>::type;
        static_assert(std::is_same<T, double>::value, "");
    }
    {
        // For functors: use < functor(Args...) >
        using T = std::result_of< my_functor(int)>::type;
        static_assert(std::is_same<T, int>::value, "");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8):

To use it you have to change from

```
std::result_of_t<A(B)>
```

to

```
std::invoke_result_t<A, B>
```

or in template

```
std::result_of_t<F(Args...)>
```

to

```
std::invoke_result_t<F,Args...>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is [*very* well-explained on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of):

> `F(Args...)` is a function type with `Args...` being the argument types and `F` being the return type.
> As such, `std::result_of` suffers from several quirks that led to its deprecation in favor of `std::invoke_result` in C++17:
>
> - `F` cannot be a function type or an array type (but can be a reference to them);
> - if any of the `Args` has type "array of `T`" or a function type `T`, it is automatically adjusted to `T*`;
> - neither `F` nor any of `Args...` can be an abstract class type;
> - if any of `Args...` has a top-level cv-qualifier, it is discarded;
> - none of `Args...` may be of type `void`.