# Use invoke_result with void argument type?

Tags: c++, c++17, void, result-of, declval

I'm trying to do the following:

```
struct Unwrapper
{
    template<typename T>
    auto operator()(const T& arg, std::enable_if_t<isPrimitive<T>, void>* = nullptr) {return arg;}

    template<typename T>
    auto operator()(const T& arg, std::enable_if_t<!isPrimitive<T>, void>* = nullptr) {return arg.wrapped();}

    void operator()(void) {}
};

template<typename T>
using UnwrappedT = std::invoke_result_t<Unwrapper, T>; // error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::invoke_result<Unwrapper, void>’
```

The [docs for std::invoke_result](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of#Notes) suggests it should work for `Args` being `void` (i.e. none), specifically it says the void case not working was a "quirk" of the now deprecated `std::result_of`.

But no, `void` doesn't work. It kind of makes sense because one also can't do `std::declval<T>()` for `T = void`, and `std::invoke_result` is supposed to be implemented in terms of `std::declval`.

Question is, what's the most elegant/direct way to patch the code to work with void? I could do something with `std::conditional` but I expected better.
(using C++17)

Relevant question: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46542077/im-not-understanding-these-uses-of-stdresult-of-and-decltype), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46021734/what-is-the-reason-for-stdresult-of-deprecated-in-c17).

Comment: Variadic template ?

Comment: good shout, but doesn't work. It is not a problem to call `unwrap()` with no-args, it's just `invoke_result_t` not working

Comment: What do you mean by "work with void"? An `Unwrapper` can't be called with an object of type `void` (because there's no objects of type `void`), so `invoke_result` is arguably doing what it's expected to do here.

Comment: @cpplearner `void` is a type, not to a full extent (as in creating and passing objects _of it_), but yes to some extents, for example you can use `return void()` syntax for uniformity with templates. I believe `void` is also a type to the extent to which you can ask "what's the return type of a method returning void". The answer is "it is `void`".

Comment: Well if you use `std::invoke_result_t<Unwrapper>` you will get `void`, but `std::invoke_result_t<Unwrapper, void>` does not exist, because `void` can't be an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
template<typename... T>
using UnwrappedT = std::invoke_result_t<Unwrapper, T...>;
```

`UnwrappedT<>` would handle the `void` case.

If you want `UnwrappedT<void>` to mean `UnwrappedT<>`, you'll need some way of dropping the `void`. `conditional` is the most familiar way of doing thay:

```
template<typename T>
using UnwrappedT = typename std::conditional_t<
    std::is_void_v<T>,
    std::invoke_result<Unwrapper>,
    std::invoke_result<Unwrapper, T>>::type;
```

Or you could have some fun with Boost.Mp11:

```
template<typename T>
using UnwrappedT = mp_apply<std::invoke_result_t,
    mp_remove_if<mp_list<Unwrapper, T>, std::is_void>>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ?

```
template<typename T>
using UnwrappedT = std::result_of_t<Unwrapper(const T&)>;
```