# How I can find type of template function return

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors, c++17

I need find type of template function result for something like this:

```
template<typename T>
T fun1(
T arg1,
result_fun<T>(some_fun)
);
```

Or something like this. So in standart library I find result_of(I find invoke_result too, it don't work too). So i find [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46021734/what-is-the-reason-for-stdresult-of-deprecated-in-c17) where I find syntax of this function. It work on [sipmle](https://ideone.com/JloELE) code [but](https://ideone.com/vfuu7x)... It don't work with pointers... example(it and ideone code equals):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
T *some(T x){
    return &x;
}

template<typename T>
void somestrange(T x, typename result_of<decltype(&some<decltype(x)>)(decltype(x))>::type z);

template<typename T>
void somestrange(T x, typename result_of<decltype(&some<decltype(x)>)(decltype(x))>::type z){
    cout << is_same<decltype(x), int>() << endl
     << is_same<decltype(z), int *>();
}

int main(){
    int x = 0;
    int *z = nullptr;
    somestrange(x, z);
    return 0;
}
```

It will be work, but if template recive pointer...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
T **some(T *x){
    return &x;
}

template<typename T>
void somestrange(T x, typename result_of<decltype(&some<decltype(x)>)(decltype(x))>::type z);

template<typename T>
void somestrange(T x, typename result_of<decltype(&some<decltype(x)>)(decltype(x))>::type z){
    cout << is_same<decltype(x), int>() << endl
     << is_same<decltype(z), int *>();
}

int main(){
    int *x = 0;
    int **z = nullptr;
    somestrange(x, z);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile will be angry. So I think what I can do. And I create own weel... So I write something like [this](https://ideone.com/dm57Gq):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

template<typename Fun, typename Arg>
inline auto myinvoke(Fun&& f, Arg&& arg)
    -> decltype(forward<Fun>(f)(forward<Arg>(arg)))
{
    return (forward<Fun>(f)(forward<Arg>(arg)));
}

template<typename Fun, typename Arg>
struct return_type {
    using type = decltype(myinvoke(declval<Fun>(), declval<Arg>()));
};

template<typename Fun, typename Arg>
using return_type_t = typename return_type<Fun, Arg>::type;


template <typename T>
T *some(T x){
    return &x;
}

template<typename T>
void somestrange(T x, return_type_t<decltype(some<T>), T> z);

template<typename T>
void somestrange(T x, return_type_t<decltype(some<T>), T> z){
    cout << is_same<decltype(x), int>() << endl
     << is_same<decltype(z), int *>();
}

int main(){
    int x = 0;
    int *z = nullptr;
    somestrange(x, z);
    return 0;
}
```

But if I here, you can guess that it don't work. And you will be right, because it doesn't work with [ptr](https://ideone.com/ypy9j0), same that can't work result_of:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

template<typename Fun, typename Arg>
inline auto myinvoke(Fun && f, Arg&& arg)
    -> decltype(forward<Fun>(f)(forward<Arg>(arg)))
{
    return (forward<Fun>(f)(forward<Arg>(arg)));
}

template<typename Fun, typename Arg>
struct return_type {
    using type = decltype(myinvoke(declval<Fun>(), declval<Arg>()));
};

template<typename Fun, typename Arg>
using return_type_t = typename return_type<Fun, Arg>::type;


template <typename T>
T **some(T *x){
    return &x;
}

template<typename T>
void somestrange(T x, return_type_t<decltype(some<T>), T> z);

template<typename T>
void somestrange(T x, return_type_t<decltype(some<T>), T> z){
    cout << is_same<decltype(x), int>() << endl
     << is_same<decltype(z), int *>();
}

int main(){
    int *x = 0;
    int **z = nullptr;
    somestrange(x, z);
    return 0;
}
```

So what I can do with it? Somebody know how I can resolve this problem(I only can use STL)? Thanks for answer

Comment: `some` has undefined behavior by returning pointer from local variable.

Comment: I know I, don't use this result it need me for explain question, sorry by that

Comment: With pointer, you need `return_type_t<decltype(some<T>), T*>`, as `T` is not a valid input parameter for `some<T>`.

Comment: Add you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53673442/simplest-way-to-determine-return-type-of-function/53673648#53673648) to get the return type of any function object.

Comment: Why? In fourth example T is int*

Comment: @NathanOliver it will be work with templates?

Comment: @Jarod42 it don't work

Comment: @NathanOliver I cheked it, but it only work on mvsc, there is no crossplatform way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
int *x = 0;
int **z = nullptr;
somestrange(x, z);
```

and

```
template<typename T>
void somestrange(T x, return_type_t<decltype(some<T>), T> z);
```

- `T` would be `int*`
- `some<T>` expects `T*` argument

So change to

```
template<typename T>
void somestrange(T* x, return_type_t<decltype(some<T>), T*> z);
```

or

```
template<typename T>
void somestrange(T* x, return_type_t<decltype(some<std::remove_pointer_t<T>>), T> z);
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/rMRIjO)

Or don't explicitly specify template, and allow deduction:

```
template<typename T>
void somestrange(T x, decltype(some(std::declval<T>())) z);
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/UtzDbh)

Comment: It work, but in my code I have function(like somestrange) wich receive pointer or smart pointer so I can't use that way

Comment: @emik_g: Others way added.